# Loop through csv with Pandas, specific column

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

With the csv module, I loop through the rows to execute logic:

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", "r") as csv_read:
r = csv.reader(csv_read, delimiter = ",")
next(r, None) #Skip headers first row
for row in rows:
    #Logic here
```

I'm new to Pandas, and I want to execute the same logic, using the *second column only* in the csv as the input for the loop.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=[1])
```

Assuming the above is correct, what should I do from here to execute the logic based on the cells in column 2?

I want to use the cell values in column 2 as input for a web crawler. It takes each result and inputs it as a search term on a webpage, and then scrapes data from that webpage. Is there any way to grab each cell value in the array rather than the whole array at the same time?

Comment: Sorry are you looking for `pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=[1])`?

Comment: Does `usecols=[2]` select the second column to work with? If so, I will edit the question.

Comment: index values start from `0` so `usecols=[1]` is the second column, this will only load the second column

Comment: you've not explained what you want to do with the row values, the idea is that you want to execute some operation on the **entire** column as a vectorised operation rather than row-wise unless you really have to

Comment: @EdChum I want to use the cell values in column 2 as input for a web crawler. It takes each result and inputs it as a search term on a webpage, and then scrapes off the website and saves it to another csv. So working with the entire column at the same time isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the pandas equivalent of your code is this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=[1])
```

So passing `usecols=[1]` will only load the second column, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).

now assuming this column has a name like 'url' but really it doesn't matter we can do something like:

```
def crawl(x):
    #do something

df.apply(crawl)
```

So in principle the above will crawl each url in your column a value at a time.

**EDIT**

You can pass param `axis=1` to `apply` so that it process each row rather than the entire column:

```
df.apply(crawl, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. So here's some of the actual code for search input. 

`def crawl(x):
 searchkey = driver.find_element_by_name("name")
 searchkey.send_keys(x)`

But for some reason it wants to search for all rows in the column at the same time. And it also includes an index number "0, 1, 2 ..." in front of the cell value.

Comment: try `df.apply(crawl, axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked beautifully. I have just one follow-up, what does `Name: 0, dtype: object ...` mean? It seems like it attaches this when I `print x`.

Comment: What you are seeing is a pandas Series with a single row value, what you're seeing is the index value as `Name: 0` and the `dtype: object` which means datatype and the datatype is a python object but in your case is a `str`, I'll update my answer so it shows what worked for you, could you accept my answer if it resolved your question, thanks.